# While loop doesn't add up my variable python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing a data scraper in python using selenium, I want to navigate through pages in a website
using a while loop for execute the scraper but i can't change my navigate variable, here is my code

```
numeros = 2
all_texts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('list')
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="listadoAgencias"]/div/div/div[3]/nav/ul/li['+str(numeros)+']/a')
veces = 1


def showall():
    for text in all_texts:
        print(text.text)
        sleep(2)


while veces < 6:
    showall()
    print('------------------------------------------')
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 3000)")
    sleep(1)
    btn.click()
    numeros += 1
    sleep(3)
```

my variable "numeros" still the same (int 2) so the `numeros += 1` is not taking effect and the app crash after go through the second page

Comment: You've set `veces=6` in the start so it should never be less than 6 in the while-loop condition

Comment: Fixed, is not part of the problem

Comment: Your code isn’t relying on the updated value of `numeros`. Unless you’ve left something out, that global code only gets run one time, with the initial value of that variable.

Comment: oh, that might be the problem @JackRyan, how can I fix that?

Comment: You need to add more details of your program so we'll know how `veces` and `numeros` are used. Update your code snippet and it will help us understand your context better.

Comment: You should probably wrap that top code in a function that takes `numeros` as an argument, and pass in the updated value each time.

Answer (score 0):

1. You've initialized `veces = 6` and while loop says `while veces < 6` which would evaluate to **FALSE** in the first attempt.
2. Also, make sure you're changing veces value (once upon iteration) so that It doesn't become an infinite loop. In such a case your program would crash.

Comment: yes fixed, but still `numeros += 1` doesn't working

Comment: Well, It should work. Do a thing print value of numeros before and after " numeros+=1 " and see If it's changing with each iteration or not.

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**

I put

`btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="listadoAgencias"]/div/div/div[3]/nav/ul/li['+str(numeros)+']/a')`

inside the while loop so now it uses the updated value of `numeros`